# How to capture start of path and rest of path in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to "proxy_pass" to an internal service based on the request path in Nginx, which I've managed to get working by doing:

```
location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
    resolver 127.0.0.1:53 ipv6=off;
    resolver_timeout  10s;
    # $1 is the regex match (i.e. the path)
    set $backend "http://$1-service/entry";
    proxy_pass $backend;
  }
```

This allows me to reverse proxy internal services, for example if I navigate to `http://my-nginx.com/some` it'll pass the request along to `http://some-service/entry`.

While this works fine I'd also like to be able to append the rest of the path to the internal service. For example if I navigate to `http://my-nginx.com/some/x/y` I'd like nginx to proxy_pass to `http://some-service/x/y` (note that I **don't** want to navigate to `http://some-service/entry/x/y`).

I've tried the following:

```
# I'd like to capture two groups, my intension is that when path 
# is "/some/x/y" then $1 should be "some" and $2 should be "/x/y"
location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?$ {
    resolver 127.0.0.1:53 ipv6=off;
    resolver_timeout  10s;

    set $backend "http://$1-service/entry";

    if ($2) {
      set $backend "http://$1-service$2"
    }

    proxy_pass $backend;
}
```

which just gives me the following error:

```
2016/06/01 14:39:58 [error] 8#8: *2827 some could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 10.240.0.4, server: nginx, request: "GET /some/x/y HTTP/1.1", host: "my-host"
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try to extract protocol from variable. `set $backend "$1-service/entry";` and `proxy_pass http://$backend;`

Comment: Hmm am I not already setting $backend to what you're suggesting? And what do you mean by extracting the protocol? How should I use it and why do I need it?

Comment: You put `http://` part into variable. I suggest not to